# use idea compile spring5 source code occur error

Tags: java, spring

when compile spring5 source code with IDEA IDE occur error：

> Error:Kotlin: [Internal Error] java.lang.LinkageError: loader
>   constraint violation: loader (instance of
>   org/jetbrains/kotlin/cli/jvm/plugins/PluginURLClassLoader$SelfThenParentURLClassLoader)
>   previously initiated loading for a different type with name
>   "kotlin/sequences/Sequence"

Answer (score 4):

Similar issue solved by updating the Kotlin version here:

IntelliJ IDEA/Preferences/Languages and Frameworks/Kotlin

There you'll see your current version and the latest available one. Install it and restart the IDE.

It looks like Kotlin (the version that you have installed right now) is not compatible with the version of Gradle installed at the moment. That was the situation observed and maybe it applies to your case.